# Prove that the following to metrics generate the same topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am studying Munkres's Topology on my own.

> Consider two metrics $d$ and $\overline{d}$ on $X$ where $\overline{d} = \text{min} \{1, d(x,y)\}$, the standard bounded metric. Let $\mathscr{T}$ and $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ are topologies generated by $d$ and $\overline{d}$ respectively.  prove $\mathscr{T} = \mathscr{T}^\prime$.

My attempt is as follows:

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the basis for $\mathscr{T}$ consisting $B_d(x, \epsilon)$ with $\epsilon >0$. And $\mathscr{B}^\prime$ be the basis for $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ consisting $B_\overline{d} (x, \epsilon)$ with $0<\epsilon <1$.

Now we notice that each basis element of $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ is an element of $\mathscr{T}$ and since each open set in $\mathscr{T}$ is union of elements of $\mathscr{B}^\prime \subset \mathscr{T}$, we conclude that $\mathscr{T}\prime \subset \mathscr{T}$, i.e., $\mathscr{T}$ is finer than $\mathscr{T}^\prime$.

Now for the other inclusion we  take an arbitrary open set $U$ in $\mathscr{T}$. Now for each $x \in U$ , there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_d(x, \epsilon) \subset U$.

- If $\epsilon<1$, we have   $B_d(x, \epsilon) = B_\overline{d} (x, \epsilon)$: We already have $ B_\overline{d} (x, \epsilon) \subset B_d(x, \epsilon)$ and to prove  $ B_d(x, \epsilon) \subset B_\overline{d} (x, \epsilon)$, take $$y \in B_d(x, \epsilon) \implies d(x,y) < \epsilon \implies d(x,y)<1 \implies \overline{d}(x,y)< \epsilon \implies y \in B_\overline{d} (x,\epsilon)$$ Hence, $ B_d(x, \epsilon) \subset B_\overline{d} (x, \epsilon)$.
- If $\epsilon>1$, then $$B_\overline{d} (x, r) \subset B_d(x, \epsilon) \subset U \space \text{where} \space r<1$$ Hence, $U \in \mathscr{T}^\prime$, so we conclude that $\mathscr{T} \subset \mathscr{T}^\prime$.

Therefore, $\mathscr{T} = \mathscr{T}^\prime$.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct but it is quite long. Here is how I would do it and that may be useful to you.

Suppose $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are the metric spaces in question (lets use easier notation). Call $B(x,r)$ an open ball radius $r$ in $(X,d)$ and $B'(x,r)$ an open ball radius $r$ in $(X,d')$.

For any open ball in $B'(x,r)$, it contains $B(x,\min\{r,1\}/2)$.

For any open ball $B(x,r)$, it contains the ball $B'(x,\min\{r,1\}/2)$.

This is equivalent to inducing the same topology, as you may see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you please explain why $B^\prime (x, \frac{r}{2}) \subset B(x,r)$?

Comment: It doesn't, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I think, you are using the second condition of [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics](Topological equivalence). That is for each $x \in X$ and $r>0$ there exist radii $r^\prime$ and $r^\prime\prime$ such that $B_d(x, r^\prime) \subset B_{d^\prime} (x,r)$ and $B_{d^\prime}(x, r^\prime\prime) \subset B_d(x,r)$. So,  for the first inclusion you are choosing $r^\prime = \text{min} \{r,1\}/2$, but about $r^\prime\prime$ for the second condition?

Comment: @user454229 I have actually said far more than I have to, see the edit with unnecessary details removed and you will see what $r'$ and $r''$ are